# Unable iterate all index when a range over JSON Array

Tags: go

I'm creating a standalone mockserver with JSON file as my input (request and response) for integration testing. I was able to serve first request only.

```
// MockServices ...
type MockServices struct {
    Request  string `json:"request"`
    Response string `json:"response"`
}

func main() {
r := getMockServices()

for i, s := range r {
    for i >= 0 {
        // fmt.Println(i)
        // fmt.Println(s.Request)
        http.HandleFunc(s.Request, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // not serving remaing endpoints
            w.Write([]byte(s.Response))
        })

        if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/_kFaxMnRTJJ

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please update with a runnable go play? and/or the exception you're seeing and the test case you're using?

Comment: Um...what is this even doing?  Assuming `getMockServices()` returns a slice, you're iterating over the slice, and then immediately initiating a second loop that continues while `i >= 0` while never decrementing `i` (which you shouldn't decrement anyway, because _it's the loop index variable_!).  You're also not running the ListenAndServe in a goroutine, and it doesn't return until the server encounters an error, so ya, it blocks on the first ListenAndServe indefinitely.

Comment: correct, I'm returning slice  `([]main.MockServices) (len=3 cap=4) {
 (main.MockServices) {
  Request: (string) (len=2) "/4",
  Response: (string) (len=1) "6"
 },
 (main.MockServices) {
  Request: (string) (len=2) "/5",
  Response: (string) (len=1) "7"
 },
 (main.MockServices) {
  Request: (string) (len=1) "/",
  Response: (string) (len=1) "5"
 }
}`

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/XghQcx6DcXM

Comment: I'm new with Go.  `ListenAndServe` gogoroutine did not build binary for me

func main() {
 h := http.NewServeMux()
 r := getMockServices()
 for _, s := range r {
  h.HandleFunc(s.Request, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   w.Write([]byte(s.Response))
  })
 }
 go func() {
  err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", h)
  log.Fatal(err)
 }()
}

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues:

- https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe always returns a Non-nil error
- You're attempting to bind to same port in a loop
- You're attempting to bind in ANOTHER loop based on the index of the mock response

Comment: Also, ListenAndServe doesn't return until the server *encounters* an error.  It will block indefinitely while the server is functioning properly.

Comment: Thank pointing out Non-nil error, I will fix it. I'm attempting to bind to same port in a loop. I tried iterate without index, I couldn't achieve it